# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)^{1-2n} (x^2-4)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I am studying the power series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)^{1-2n} (x^2-4)^n.$$

${\bf My \ solution:}$ having $f_n(x) =\left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)^{1-2n}$, I test the necessary condition for the convergence. It is
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)^{1-2n} (x^2-4)^n = 0\iff 0<x^2-4<1,$$
i.e. the series could converge iff $-\sqrt{5}<x<-2 \cup 2<x<\sqrt{5}$.

I proceed finding the convergence ray $R$ by applying the Cauchy-Hadamard criterion. It is
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{2n+1}{n}\right)^{1-2n}} =1,$$
so $R=1$ and the series converges absolutely in $(3, 5)$ and totally in every $[a, b]\subset (3, 5)$.

Taking into account the range of the necessary condition, the above considerations hold true in $(3, \sqrt{5})$ and for the intervals $[a, b]\subset (3, \sqrt{5})$.

Does my reasonings hold true? Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you find that limit is $1$? That limit is the same as from the following sequence:

$$\Big(\frac{1+2n}{n}\Big)^{\frac{1-2n}{n}}$$
Where inside the parenthesis we have limit $2$, and on the exponent $-2$, thus:
$$\lim_n\Big(\frac{1+2n}{n}\Big)^{\frac{1-2n}{n}}=2^{-2}\implies \frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{4}\implies R=4$$

Provided you prove the coefficient has finite limit, which is true as it converges to some power of $e$, the (necessary but not sufficient) criteria for convergence is met.

Now you should be able to proceed on your own (but notice that $\sqrt{5}<3$).

The rest of your reasoning works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand my mistake. I have a question: why $|x^2-4|\le 1$ is needed instead of $(x^2-4)\le 1$ as I wrote? (I am gonna post my revised solution once I understand this thing).

Comment: My mistake, you were right saying $0<x^2-4<1$.

Comment: Ok, I edit again my comment. Since $R=4$, we have that the series does converge absolutely if $|x^2-4|\le 4\iff 0<x< 2\sqrt{2}$, but taking into account the limit of the necessary condition, the absolute convergence is guaranteed in $(2, \sqrt{5})$ whence the total in $[a, b]\subset (2, \sqrt{5})$. Could you please tell me if it is correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|x^2-4|\leq4\iff |x|\leq 2\sqrt{2}$? However, up to mistakes in the interval your reasoning works.